# Aot: Calling function 'makeDecorator', function calls are not supported

Tags: angular, aot

When I run:

```
ngc -p ./tsconfig.prod.json
```

I got the following error:
*Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function '**makeDecorator**', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function, resolving symbol Injectable in /node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/metadata.d.ts, resolving symbol **OpaqueToken** in node_modules/ng2ignalr/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/opaque_token.d.ts, resolving symbol OpaqueToken in /node_modules/ng2signalr/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/opaque_token.d.ts

I use:

```
"@angular/compiler": "^2.4.2",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.2"
```

Anyone an idea on how to fix this ?

Comment: Could this be related to AOT compiler issue that ignores "main" defined inside package.json?